# Des stylo ou des stylos ?

Tags: accord, abréviations

Sachant que le mot *stylo* est une abréviation de *stylographe*, doit-on l'accorder au pluriel en disant *des stylos* ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Des stylos.

À ma connaissance, le fait que ce soit à l'origine une abréviation ne change rien. On écrit aussi des radios, des télés, des autos, etc.

Comment: On ajoute parfois même un "s" au pluriel des sigles et acronymes, comme "des CDs" ou "des TVs". Je pense aussi à "BDs", que j'ai déjà vu écrit "bédés". Je ne dirais toutefois pas que ces orthographes sont correctes, mais on peut certainement les croiser.

Comment: @Rightleg Il me semble qu'en français on n'ajoute pas de s à la fin des sigles et acronymes (sauf s'ils sont devenus des noms comme "radar"). C'est un anglicisme de le faire.

Comment: @NajibIdrissi Oui, on ajouterait un 's' aux acronymes et non aux sigles... C'est ce que semble dire [cette page](http://francite.net/education/grammatika/page36.html), ainsi que [celle-là](http://www.les-abreviations.com/definitions.html).

Comment: @Rightleg Euh, quoi ? Ce n'est pas ce qui est écrit dans ces pages...?! Il est bien écrit que les acronymes *et* les sigles sont invariables, *sauf* si c'est un acronyme devenu un nom commun (radar, laser, ovni...).

Comment: Bon pas man d'avis divergents… des sources ? Je ne trouve rien sur le site de l'académie française.